# Positioning/ Size of MarginText in CV (classicthesis/curvvita)

Tags: macros, positioning, geometry, marginpar

I'm trying to write my CV in LaTeX, with classicthesis and curvvita for style format.

I've got the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedright \textsc \small#1}}
\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Sept 2015-Present} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{0.5em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

\begin{cv}{{ \hspace{1mm} John Smith}}\vspace{1em} % Your name

\vspace{0.5em} % Extra space between major sections

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Education}\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{Sept. 2010- April 2012}} \textsc{XYZ University, ABC, DE} \newline Bachelor of Science, Physics \newline  
Some stuff goes here} 

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{Sept. 2012- April 2015}} \textsc{XYZ High School, ABC, DE} \newline High School Diploma $\cdotp$ GPA: x.x/x.x\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Dean's Honour List \newline}
\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

This produces:
[image]

I want to change the width of the "MarginText" element (the one with the Sept. 2010-April 2012 dates) so that the dates fit one one line. I tried using the geometry package to change it, but that only changes the margin to the left of the margintext element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the width of the marginpar-column as well as the width of the left margin. Option `showframe` helps us in visualizing the page layout. Please note the additional paragraph indent.

[image: meganCurrCvMarginparwidth]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar 
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} 
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedright \textsc \small#1}}
\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{marginparwidth=4cm,left=5cm,showframe}%<-----



\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 
\vspace{0.5em}} 
\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{0.5em}} 
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} 

\begin{cv}{{ \hspace{1mm} John Smith}}\vspace{1em} 

    \vspace{0.5em} 

    \spacedlowsmallcaps{Education}\vspace{1em}

    \Description{\MarginText{\textsc{Sept. 2010- April 2012}} \textsc{XYZ University, ABC, DE} \newline Bachelor of Science, Physics \newline  
Some stuff goes here} 

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{Sept. 2012- April 2015}} \textsc{XYZ High School, ABC, DE} \newline High School Diploma $\cdotp$ GPA: x.x/x.x\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Dean's Honour List \newline}
\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adjusting `{Sept 2015-Present}` in the below line of the code.
For example write: `{September 2015 - Present}`

```
\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Sept 2015-Present}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This doesn't actually seem to work, did you test the OPs code with your modification?